# dash lights stay on after aftermarket tail light install

Tags: honda, lights

After installing aftermarket tail lights on my 94 Honda Prelude Si, the broken lamp light and hand brake (!) Dash lights stay on with the ignition switiched on. All of the tail lights work and the dash lights were fine before the swap.

Comment: Check the grounds, that may be the issues. Do you still have the old taillights? If so, may re-installed them to make sure that it's not a coincidence.

Comment: Are you sure that all the cables are well isolated and there is no unwanted contact between them?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install LED lighting instead of incandescent lighting? LEDs don't draw as much current as incandescent, so your Honda may think (because of the low current draw) that you have a failed taillight bulb. You may have to intentionally add extra current load at the taillights to make that dash light go away.

The hand brake light, though, would be a totally different issue. THAT should be controlled only by a switch on the hand brake.

Comment: Have no leds, will try reinstall. I am a noob so where would the ground be?

Comment: Plugs may be an issue but they look ok.

Comment: The ground for a taillight might be a bit hard to find - follow the wire loom from the taillight housing until you can find a wire that breaks out of the bundle and runs to a screw into sheet metal somewhere. That'd be the most likely ground connection for that light housing.